# Symfony action name in template

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

How can I get the action name inside a template? The template is actually a partial.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should try :

```
$sf_params->get('action')
```

Comment: This is probably better because i think its directly tied to the initial action parsed by the router...

Comment: is that an instance of sfParameterHolder?

Comment: `$sf_request sfRequest` 
`$sf_context sfContext` 
`$sf_user    myUser` 
`$sf_params  sfParameterHolder`

Answer (score 4):

The `sfContext` instance should be automagically exposed in the view layer as `$sf_context` so you could do: `$sf_context->getActionName()`.

However i think this may not necessarily be the action youre looking for, because i think it may be the current action being processed which if its a partial for a component would be the component's action. Not 100% on that as ive never had a need to use/investigate :-)

Comment: can you tell me what variables are exposed where? like sfContext, sf_user, ...? thanks for quick reply btw. :)

Comment: and it says 

`Notice: Undefined variable: sfContext in /var/www/weblog/apps/backend/modules/poster/templates/_form.php on line 5 Fatal error: Call to a member function getActionName() on a non-object in /var/www/weblog/apps/backend/modules/poster/templates/_form.php on line 5`

so, no

Comment: its `$sf_context` not `sfContext`... thats the class name :-)